# Problems setting up mediaelement.js

Tags: html, video, mediaelement.js

I cant seem to get mediaelement.js running on a simple page, I have followed the set up instructions but the video is still used in its native state, mediaelement doesn't fire.

The javascript and css and jquery are all linking correctly but its not working.

Any ideas?

http://3letterit.com/manual/media.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Manwell Pages</title>
    <script src="build/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/mediaelementplayer.css" />
    <script>
// using jQuery
$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer(/* Options */);</script>

</head>

<body>
<div>           
<video src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/cgp_video/mymovie.mp4" width="320" height="240" controls ></video>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of $('video,audio').mediaelementplayer(/* Options */)
use

```
window.onload = function() {  $('video,audio').mediaelementplayer(/* Options */); };
```

When you call $('video,audio').mediaelementplayer(/* Options */),

there are not any media elements yet.

Comment: No that doesn't change anything

Comment: On your page, you forgot closing "}".

Comment: thanks yavuzkaus that did it, so also can use
`$(document).ready(function() {
  // jQuery method
 $('video, audio').mediaelementplayer();
  
 });`